# Gradle BuildConfigFields Syntax

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

What could be wrong with this syntax? I am getting Gradle DSL method not found:'buildConfigFields()' error.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.okason.drawingapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


        def filesAuthorityValue = applicationId + ".files"

        //Now you can use ${filesAuthority} in your manifest
        manifestPlaceholders = [filesAuthority: filesAuthorityValue]

        //Now you can use BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY in our code
        buildConfigFields "String", "FILES_AUTHORITY", "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\""
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be using `buildConfigField` and not `buildConfigFields`

Change

```
//Now you can use BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY in our code
buildConfigFields "String", "FILES_AUTHORITY", "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\""
```

to

```
//Now you can use BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY in our code
buildConfigField "String", "FILES_AUTHORITY", "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\""
```

are you sure that `buildConfigFields` even exits ?